# Loops and guesses

Tags: numerics, infinite-loop, discretization

I have to solve a system of equations in the following way: I first guess a value for a variable, let's call it `y`, calculate another variable `z`, which is a function of `y`, `z(y)`, and then check if another condition was met on `z`. The simplest example that slightly resembles my problem looks like this:

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
y = 1; (*initial guess*)
z = x /. FindRoot[a*x + Log[x] - Log[y], {x, 0.01}];
FOCy = b*y + Log[y] + Log[z]
```

So I should keep doing this while `FOCy` is different than `0`.

I usually use MATLAB for these kind of problem. There, I would discretize `y` on a grid and I would use a "shooting algorithm" (a fixed point using Intermediate Value Theorem). On Mathematica, I don't know what would be the recommended way to proceed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include both equations in your [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) call:

```
a=2; b=3;
FindRoot[{b y+Log[y]+Log[z],a z+Log[z]-Log[y]},{{y,1},{z,1}}]
```

> {y -> 0.57516, z -> 0.309632}

Comment: That can clearly be done in my example above, indeed, @carlwoll. I am going to check if it works in my problem and I get back to you.